# how to take a subarray, and flatten it back into parent array?

Tags: ruby

```
parent = ["A","B","C",["a","b", "c", "d"], "D"]

parent.each do |children|

if children.is_a?

children.flatten # how do i insert it back to parent
# so that this loop can continue looping through the remainder
#including the newly flattened children(a,b,c,d)

end

end
```

The question is, once an array is discovered, i flatten it, and need it to be inserted it to the original parent array, so that A,B,C,a,b,c,d,D will be looped once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the description it seems that you would be able to do

```
parent.flatten.each do |child|
end
```

Comment: When you say "need it to be inserted it to the original parent array" you mean you want the flattened contents to overwrite the original contents, modify the iterator to read:
`parent.flatten!.each do |child|
...
end`

Comment: yes that makes sense. as flatten! overwrites itself. flatten produces new array. thank you.